# Can't dequeue operators from one queue to another by checking if character is an operator through a boolean method that uses switch

Tags: java, stack, queue, infix-notation, postfix-mta

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = 'x';
Queue q1 = new Queue();
Stack s1 = new Stack();
s1.push('#');
Queue q2 = new Queue();
q1.enqueue('#');

while (c != '#') {
    System.out.println("Enter a character: ");
    c = input.next().charAt(0);
    q1.enqueue(c);
}       
while (c != '#') {
    c = (char) q1.dequeue();
    if (!operator(c)) {
        q2.enqueue(c);
    }
}
q1.print(q1);
System.out.println();
q2.print(q2);

}

public static boolean operator(char c) {
 char op = 'x';
 boolean isOperator;

 switch (op) {
 case '*':
 case '/':
 case '^':
 case '+':
 case '-':
     isOperator = true;
     break;
 default:
     isOperator = false;
     break;
}
return isOperator;
 }
}
```

The goal for this is for me to enter some characters into queue q1, then while the character isn't a #, it should dequeue from q1 as long as the character isn't an operator and enqueue it into q2.
However, none of my operators from q1 are getting dequeued and enqueued into q2 which should be happening from lines 20-23.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the variable `c` that is not resetted before doing the second while.

If you go out the first 'while' loop, `c` will be setted to '#' and you will not go in the second loop.

Try this:

```
while (c != '#') {
    System.out.println("Enter a character: ");
    c = input.next().charAt(0);
    q1.enqueue(c);
}       
c = 'a'
while (c != '#') {
    c = (char) q1.dequeue();
    if (!operator(c)) {
        q2.enqueue(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that helps since I enqueue a # at the start of the code.

Comment: Have you tried? You are checking 'c' not q1 in the condition!

Comment: Yes, it still prints the result and it all stays in q1.

Comment: Ok I think I'm figuring it out.. will post back when back from work.

Comment: The problem is maybe your implementation of enqueue. The problem in this code was only that one. Without setting c, the code cannott work!